# How to make input string taken as it is instead of only the first character?

Tags: c++, string, menu

I want to create a menu where there is both letter and number.

I tried to use string but now when user input 20, it will only take the first number, which is 2. How do I make so that when user put 20, it will be seen as 20 instead of 2?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string choice;
cout << "1. A" << endl;
cout << "2. B" << endl;
cout << "3. C" << endl;
cout << "4. D" << endl;
cout << "Q. Quit" << endl;
do
{
    cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice[0] == '1')
    {
    cout << "1";
    } else if (choice[0] == '2')
    {
        cout << "2";
    }  else if (choice[0] == '3')
    {
        cout << "3";
    } else if (choice[0] == '4')
    {
        cout << "4";
    } else if (choice[0] == 'q' || choice[0] == 'Q')
    {
        cout << "q";
    } else {
            cout << "Please choose one of the menu above. " << endl;
    }        
} while (choice[0] != 1 && choice[0] != 2 && choice[0] != 3 && choice[0] != 4 && choice[0] != 'q');
return 0;
}
```

You also can see my code at http://cpp.sh/7ipv

Comment: Your while loop condition looks wrong, you probably want `choice[0] != '1'` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code treats `20` as  `2` because it sees only the first character of the input.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string choice;
    cout << "1. A" << endl;
    cout << "2. B" << endl;
    cout << "3. C" << endl;
    cout << "4. D" << endl;
    cout << "Q. Quit" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "1")
        {
        cout << "1";
        } else if (choice == "2")
        {
            cout << "2";
        }  else if (choice == "3")
        {
            cout << "3";
        } else if (choice == "4")
        {
            cout << "4";
        } else if (choice == "q" || choice == "Q")
        {
            cout << "q";
        } else {
                cout << "Please choose one of the menu above. " << endl;
        }        
    } while (choice != "1" && choice != "2" && choice != "3" && choice != "4" && choice != "q" && choice != "Q");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm new to c++. When I put this into my codes, it come out with: Result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified. Why does it work fine when it's just these line of code and not when there is other lines? cpp.sh/843d

Comment: I found the difference now. Didn't realised you've removed the [0]. Sorry for the trouble. Thank you!